# Display always side menu (drawer) on large devices like tablets [react-native-navigation]

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm developing an app for Android with React Native.
I handle the navigation with the package React Native Navigation from Wix, and I have a doubt.

Now I have mi app working nice on my mobile, but actually, the target is for tablets. I have a sideMenu (aka Drawer) for navigation. In mobile is always closed, and I can open it with a hamburguer button on TopBar, or swiping from the left edge of screen.
But, when the App is running on tablet, I want side menu was always shown, in all cases.

One way to do this is with Dimensions API and playing with height/width, even so I'm not sure that I could change the Navigation without reset all navigation and components (setRoot..).

I want achieve a behaviour like has the Settings Android App in mobile and tablets.

You may think the other famous package for navigation React Navigation is better to to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setDrawerEnabled()](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=setdrawerenabledparams-). To distinguish between platforms/devices you could take a look into the code in [this repository (react-native-device-detection)](https://github.com/m0ngr31/react-native-device-detection/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: The first link is broken, results in 404 error. I think that you linked is for old version (V1). On the other hand, the react-native-device-detection package seems nice :)